# Method summary best practices

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented

### Are there best practices for method summaries?

---

I'm a bit confused as to what belongs in the **parameter** and **returns** description when both are objects.

Here is an example of a method I am summarizing:

```
public class DocumentRequestObject
{
        public List<UserIds> UserIds { get; set; } // User Ids being searched for document
        public string DocumentID { get; set; } // DocumentId being requested
}

public class DocumentReturnObject
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; } // Success, fail, etc.
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a customer document summary object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">A customer document request object that requires UserId(s) and the document Id being requested. </param>
    /// <returns>Response Code and document information.</returns>
    public DocumentReturnObject GetDocument(DocumentRequestObject dro)
    {
        // Some logic to search UserIds for requested DocumentId
        // Return DocumentReturnObject populated with details
    }
}
```

This is meant to be an opinion based question; I've simply been unable to find any information on the internet that addresses this issue. If this is an inappropriate question for SE, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Software Engineering! Please look at the "questions to avoid" page https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. You are likely to get this question closed if it is too broad or opinion based.

Comment: [The problem with "best practice" questions...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937)

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you for the read, that's a good point.

Comment: That the real objects are 10+ properties most of which are optional suggests perhaps using more targeted types -- or quite in the other direction, generic self-describing combinable query-fragment objects.

Comment: I might first try to document the abstraction represented by the class itself, and then the methods in the context of that class documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look at your example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a customer document summary object.
/// </summary>
```

I know that already by looking at the method signature.

```
/// <param name="request">The request object</param>
```

I know that already by looking at the formal parameter's signature.

```
/// <returns>The return object</returns>
```

This comment is so generic that I actually know more by observing the return type than I do from the comment.

```
/// <param name="request">
/// A customer document request object that requires UserId(s) and the document Id being requested. 
/// </param>
```

This is the only comment that might actually contain a scrap of useful information.  However, what are you telling me that I don't already know by looking at the `DocumentRequestObject` class?

Comments should tell me *why,* not *how* or *what.* The code will tell me that.

If all you're doing is repeating type names in the comments, you're probably better off avoiding them entirely and saving yourself the maintenance headaches.

Comment: The real objects are slightly more complex with 10+ properties. In the existing code, often a request object is sent as a parameter to a method but only uses 1-2 of the properties. I was thinking it would be useful to specify exactly _what_ the method expects from these generic objects.

Comment: Consider providing only the summary comment (in a bit more detail than that provided here), unless the way parameters are handed to the method requires additional explanation.  Visual Studio already tells the consumer of your class detailed information about the parameters.  If the properties need documenting, do that in the "real objects."

Comment: +1 for "why not how". Refactoring should impact code not comments.

Comment: What's an example of _why_? Would this be _why_ you would use this method?

Comment: Anything that is not obvious from the method's signature and code.  One commonly overlooked "why" is describing how the method or class fits into the overall architecture.  Sample code demonstrating proper usage is incredibly useful for complex classes or methods.  Sometimes, rather than explaining the method in the comment, it's better to rename or refactor it so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Don't explain the members of the request and response objects-- you can explain those in the code comments within those classes, and the comments are more likely to stay up to date when located with the class they document.

Do explain the behavior that is exhibited by `GetDocument`.

Do not explain what the types are, since those can easily by seen by the developer.

Do explain what happens in significant edge cases, e.g. if the call doesn't find anything.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a document from XXXX based on search criteria.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">Criteria for the search.</param>
/// <returns>A document matching the search criteria; null if not found.</returns>
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is don't waste time on summary comments. However if you are being forced to do so I recommend something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a method. It gets a document.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">The request object</param>
/// <returns>The return object</returns>
public DocumentReturnObject GetDocument(DocumentRequestObject dro)
{

}
```

Edit:
Just to note, a lot of the time, a perceived need for summary comments is alleviated by changing the method signature to include more info.

```
public class CustomerDocumentService
{
    public DocumentInfo GetDocumentInfoForUsers(string documentId, List<UserIds> users)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods may be part of an API that another group of developers may use, so there is a reason for the madness.

Comment: If you've ever had to pick up a highly complex codebase without much info, you'll appreciate it when someone took the time to explain what on earth is going on.

Comment: What I don't appreciate is a complex codebase littered with summary comments that just repeat what the method signature already states.